# How to temporarily disable OpenGL command queueing, for more accurate profiling results?

Tags: performance, opengl, asynchronous, profiling, opengl-3

In Mac OS X's OpenGL Profiler app, I can get statistics regarding how long each GL function call takes.  However, the results show that a ton of time is spent in flush commands (`glFlush`, `glFlushRenderAPPLE`, `CGLFlushDrawable`) and in `glDrawElements`, and every other GL function call's time is negligibly small.

I assume this is because OpenGL is enqueueing the commands I submit, and waiting until flushing or drawing to actually execute the commands.

I guess I could do something like this:

```
glFlush();
startTiming();
glDoSomething();
glFlush();
stopTimingAndRecordDelta();
```

...and insert that pattern around every GL function call my app makes, but that would be tedious since there are thousands of GL function calls throughout my app, and I'd have to tabulate the results manually (instead of using the already-existent OpenGL Profiler tool).

So, is there a way to disable all OpenGL command queueing, so I can get more accurate profiling results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is there a way to disable all OpenGL command queueing, ...

No, there isn't an OpenGL function that does that.

> ..., so I can get more accurate profiling results?

You can get more accurate information than you are currently, but you'll never get really precise answers (but you can probably get what you need).  While the results of OpenGL rendering are the "same" — OpenGL's not guaranteed to be pixel-accurate across implementations — they're supposed to be very close.  However, how the pixels are generated can vary drastically.  In particular, tiled-reneders (in mobile and embedded devices) usually don't render pixels during a draw call, but rather queue up the geometry, and generate the pixels at buffer swap.

That said, for profiling OpenGL, you want to use `glFinish`, instead of `glFlush`.  `glFinish` will force all pending OpenGL calls to complete and return; `glFlush` merely requests that commands be sent to the OpenGL "at some time in the future", so it's not deterministic.  Be sure to remove your `glFinish` in your "production" code, since it will really slow down your application.  From your example, if you replace the flushes with finishes in your example, you'll get more interesting information.

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Synchronization was helpful in understanding the difference between glFlush and glFinish.

Answer (score 2):

You are using OpenGL 3, and in particular discussing OS X. Mavericks (10.9) supports [Timer Queries](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Query_Object#Timer_queries), which you can use to time a single GL operation or an entire sequence of operations at the pipeline level. That is, how long they take to execute when GL actually gets around to performing them, rather than timing how long a particular API call takes to return (which is often meaningless). You can only have a single timer query in the pipeline at a given time unfortunately, so you may have to structure your software cleverly to make best use of them if you want command-level granularity.

I use them in my own work to time individual stages of the graphics engine. Things like how long it takes to update shadow maps, build the G-Buffers, perform deferred / forward lighting, individual HDR post-processing effects, etc. It really helps identify bottlenecks if you structure the timer queries this way instead of focusing on individual commands.

For instance on some filtrate limited hardware shadow map generation is the biggest bottleneck, on other shader limited hardware, lighting is. You can even use the results to determine the optimal shadow map resolution or lighting quality to meet a target framerate for a particular host without requiring the user to set these parameters manually. If you simply timed how long the individual operations took you would never get the bigger picture, but if you time entire sequences of commands that actually do some major part of your rendering you get neatly packed information that can be a lot more useful than even the output from profilers.